# How to resubmit the job in Spark after it is done?

Tags: apache-spark

I am currently not using spark streaming. I have a ETL pipeline and I want to just resubmit the job after it is done. Like a typical cron job but using only Spark API's. is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [SparkLauncher](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/launcher/package-summary.html) and try something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher;

public class MyLauncher {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      while(true){
           Process spark = new SparkLauncher()
             .setAppResource("app.jar")
             .setMainClass("package.MainClass")
             .setMaster("local")
             .setConf(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_MEMORY, "1g")
             .launch();
           spark.waitFor(); <-- Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated.
      }
   }
}
```

With this you are able to submit job programatically with `SparkLauncher`. `launch()` returns java `Process` and you will simply wait until Process finish and after that in a `while` just resubmit your job.

I am not aware that `spark-submit` can resumbit job by itself.

Comment: It would have been great if SparkLauncher had some way to set SparkConf so I could simply do Process spark = new SparkLauncher().setSparkConf(sparkConf).launch()

Comment: Sure, but basically if you need it, you can done something like you want by extending SparkLauncher and create `setSparkConf(SparkConf sparkConf)` and for SparkConf `getAll` configuration and set it in for loop with `setConf(actConf.key, actConf.value)`